# How can I draw a line from center to custom angle in pi chart? I am using danielgindi/Charts

Tags: swift, charts, line, draw, pie-chart

[image]

I use to show the time periods of a day.

I want use this red line for current time show. And I want to select current time part. Thanks for all answers.

```
 setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double], timeName:String, timeLive:String) {

    var dataEntries = [PieChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry =  PieChartDataEntry(value: values[i], label: dataPoints[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Unit Sold")
    pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 3
    pieChartDataSet.selectionShift = 15



    let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)

    let pFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    pFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
    pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    pFormatter.multiplier = 1
    //pFormatter.percentSymbol = " %"
    pieChartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: pFormatter))

    pieChartData.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)!)
    pieChartData.setValueTextColor(.white)

    pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

    self.pieChartView.data = pieChartData
    self.pieChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
    // self.pieChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0,easingOption: .easeOutElastic)

    let highlight = pieChartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
    pieChartView.highlightValue(highlight)

    var attrString: NSMutableAttributedString?

    let paragraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

    attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HKJGH JHGHG ")
    attrString?.setAttributes([
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: NSUIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: NSUIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0),
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ], range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString!.length))

}
```

Comment: you are using third party ?

Comment: how yoy are creating this cart ? using CALayer ?

Comment: yes I using Charts Librariy  from danielgindi. you can look from github :  https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts